# Can not put a bot for the server of the game Go

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bots

I can not put a [bot](http://pachi.or.cz/) for the server of the game Go.

I get this error

```
kl@ox:~/kgsBot/kgsGtp$ java -jar kgsGtp.jar pachi.config
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar 
sep 15, 2015 2:01:09 AM com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient main
FINE: KGS GTP Client v3.5.20 starting up
sep 15, 2015 2:01:10 AM com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient main
SEVERE: Fatal exception
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./pachi": error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
    at com.gokgs.client.gtp.GtpClient.main(kgsgtp:918)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 4 more
```

What is the problem it?

Comment: Please provide additional information. As-is, this question means almost nothing.

Comment: I know what means Permission denied. But why "Permission denied" don't know.

Comment: CollinD
There is a game server of Go http://www.gokgs.com/. To him there GTP Engine http://www.gokgs.com/download.jsp for bots. I found the bot http://pachi.or.cz/

In windows bot is not working. I tried to put in Ubuntu. First has set of Java 8. Then the bot and through GTP Engine tried to run a bot. and I get "Permission denied"

Comment: @Gokul_uf The same error

Comment: error=13 means that you don't have the execute permission for the file. Find out where `pachi` file is and add the execute permission with `chmod`

Comment: @Gokul_uf Yes, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your stack trace,

`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./pachi": error=13, Permission denied`

`Error=13` means that you don't have the execute permission for the file. Find out where `pachi` file is using `find -name pachi` and add the execute permission with `chmod`